# JAVA - Alternative to Apache POI to read old Excel files

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am having some troubles while trying to read an old version XLS file (Biff4), using Apache POI. It doesn't have many resources to work with this type of Excel files, althought it's easy to use the Apache POI with newer XLS files.

Do I have any other good alternative to work with this old files?

Comment: One we used to like for biff files was http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/ . It's more low level than POI but generally speaking faster and much less memory hungry. But then, BIFF4 is really **beyond** old...

Comment: According to my info that's Excel 4.0, anno 1992? Never tested it on files of that era tbh.

Comment: @fvu, thanks, I will take a look on jexcelapi. But yeah, it's a very old file format, and it's generated from a system I don't have acess. :/

Comment: Apache POI has some basic low-level support for really old Excel files, aimed at text extraction. Would using that not be enough for you? See https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/src/java/org/apache/poi/hssf/extractor/OldExcelExtractor.java for what's needed